# Getting "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]" when tries to install apk on Xamarin Android Player

Tags: ruby, calabash, calabash-android, xamarin-android-player

When I try to install apk on Xamarin Android Player I'm getting next error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

I use:

- Xamarin Android Player
- Nexus 5 Lollipop Android 5.1.0 - API 22

USB Debugging is allowed and it displays in attached devices list (adb devices)

Answer (score 0):

`INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` : This error says that you try to install an app that has native libraries and they don't match with your CPU architecture. Make sure to compile the app for the CPU architecture *(armeabi-v7a/Intel)* of the test device. E.g if the app is compiled for **arm** and the deployment device has **Intel** this error will be shown.